# How to convert a tensor into a sparse integer encoding in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to implement a function that converts a TF tensor of probability distributions to sparse integer encoding of categories.  I don't think I'm going about it the right way.  How do I get the expected output that I'm looking for?

My function:

```
def into_sparse(x):
    sparseData = tf.sparse.from_dense(x)
    return sparseData
```

Function call:

```
y_sparse = into_sparse(y)
```

Input (y):

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.9933 0.     0.0067]
 [0.5065 0.1863 0.3072]
 [0.0751 0.9148 0.0102]
 [0.4307 0.0432 0.5261]], shape=(4, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Output:

```
<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor at 0x7f3543aaa610>
```

Expected Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([0, 0, 1, 2])>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use argmax. That will give you the index that contains the maximum value in a dimension.

```
tf.math.argmax(y_sparse, axis=-1)
```

See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/argmax

This is different from the sparse arrays in `tf.sparse`. Those arrays have many zeros, and storing them in a sparse format rather than dense can save space.